Why is my postgres constraint name suffix different from the standard?
In this SO answer:
PostgreSQL: default constraint names
It would appear that my foreign key (not named at time of table creation) should have defaulted to the suffix _fkey...
But it seems to have instead defaulted to the suffix _foreign instead. Is this normal?
I am worried about creating a migration where I assume the constraint name and it works in my environment and then breaks everywhere else...
Is there way to ensure I reference the constraint correctly in any environment?
Updated with info:

posgres version: 16.4

client that created the key: knex

The complete FK command used: table.foreign('userId').references('users.id')

psql with \d:
I'm sorry but I am not allowed to post code from our codebase, so here it is with redactions:


Indexes:
    "***_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "***" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("***Id", "***Id")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "***_***id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("***Id") REFERENCES ***(id)
    "***_userid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id)    <=== the column of interest


Not near enough information, add to the question text as text update: 1) Postgres version. 2) What client(and version) you used to create the FK. 3) The complete  FK command used. 4) Using psql the output of \d <the_table_name>.

If they were not created in the command the table was created, then how were they?
There is no default name for constraints which are added by ALTER TABLE, so it can't be different from the default if there is no default.

You appear to be creating the table using the knex framework. Is it possible the framework is specifying the foreign key constraint name according to its own convention, overriding the default that PostgreSQL would use?

table.foreign('userId').references('users.id') is not a SQL command to create a foreign key. If your code (including migrations) depend on a name, you should use that name. If you don't use a specific name you'd better be prepared for problems.

@AdrianKlaver info added.

@jjanes : you mis-read. "If they were not created in the command", no the constraint was created when the table was created. the name was not provided, so postgres named it.

@BillKarwin you were right!

https://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#foreign shows the syntax:
table.foreign(columns, [foreignKeyName])
[.onDelete(statement).onUpdate(statement).withKeyName(foreignKeyName).deferrable(type)]

This appears to show an optional method withKeyName() you can use to specify the constraint name.
I'm not a user of knex, so I'm not going to test this. Give it a try!
Edit: If you don't specify the constraint name, knex chooses one, and it may not be the same as PostgreSQL's own default. That is, the knex framework does specify a constraint name, whether it's one you specify or not.
You noticed the documentation states this:

A default key name using the columns is used unless foreignKeyName is specified.


actually, your earlier comment under my question seems to be the correct answer, if you want to change your answer! Knex states A default key name using the columns is used unless foreignKeyName is specified. !

Then ALTER your table to change the foreign key constraint the way you want it. You can use knex for this, or else do it directly in PostgreSQL.
